# Need a Regular Expression for

Tags: c#, .net, regex

All,

C#, Regex
I need regular expression that requires to extract any alpha-numeric value that is surrounded by parentheses. Note about parentheses: There could be any number of parentheses on each side, but the number of parentheses on each side match (see Ex below).

Ex. Values (extract value of '1' from parentheses on each side):

(1) -> 1

((1)) -> 1

(((1))) -> 1

I have this expression but obviously its wrong and not sure how to preserve the value between (), etc.

```
\\(([^)]*)\\)
```

Comment: I've read a lot of not so well formated question from new user, but you have 380 rep, please, format it correctly...

Comment: I re-formatted the question.

Comment: What is your ***question***?  Questions end with a question mark (***?***)!

Comment: Can't you only replace the "(" and ")" strings with `String.Empty`? If you can use `.Replace()` method, i think Regex isn't necessary. Thomas' answer explains how to do this.

Comment: What is your question? Doesn't have to be in a form of a question friend: Re-stmt: Need regular expression that requires to extract any alpha-numeric value that is surrounded by parentheses

Comment: `.*[a-z0-9].* -` will find it

Comment: Why do you need a plus sign for parenthsis?  You really don't care how many nested parenthesis are around the value.  The pattern you provided still should work.  The error may be in the surrounding code you didn't provide.

Comment: What about `(((1))` - should this input be stripped from the brackets? Should it be kept intact or should it result in `(1`?

Comment: I clarified in the comments that parentheses match on each side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Replace();

```
string myString = "(((1))) - 1";
myString = myString.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use a regex?

As Victor suggested in the comment, why not simply

```
var number = someString.Replace("(", String.Empty).Replace(")", String.Empty);
```

Alternatively, use `LastIndexOf` and `IndexOf` and on `"("` and `")"` in conjunction with `Substring` to determine where the value is.

Answer (score 0):

```
\(([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\)
```

Matches all alpha-numeric strings enclosed in single parentheses. If you want to also check the number of parentheses on each side (unclear from the question), regex isn't the best option.